# CSS Horizontal list scrolling?

Tags: jquery, css

Given a list of links, i.e.

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">item 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">item 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">item 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">item 4</a></li>
</ul>
```

set to be displayed `inline`, can anyone recommend a jQuery plugin that will allow for scrolling this list? Say I set the containing `ul` tag to have a `width` of `30px`, the list will be cut off.

Ideally, the plugin should have "arrows" that allow scrolling left and/or right, depending upon the position the user is at in the list.

Thanks very much! :)

Comment: What are the logical steps that lead you to believe you needed jQuery to accomplish this?

Comment: @Incognito : http://www.doxdesk.com/img/updates/20091116-so-large.gif :-D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Plugin?

The greatest plugin of them all is called `CSS`:

```css
ul {
    width: 30px;
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/aZSXc/)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need a "Slider". Just about any will do, and they all typically work with LI.
Here's a few.
[25 Sliders and Tutorials](http://naldzgraphics.net/tutorials/25-must-learn-slider-tutorials-with-jquery/)